# Allowing ::1 on busybox httpd

Tags: linux, webserver, busybox

I'm running busybox 1.23.2 (compiled by myself from source) on Linux. I'm trying to prevent other people from accessing the files I put on my server, so I thought I'd configure the server:

```
$ cat etc/httpd1.conf
A: 127.
D: *
$ sudo httpd -h www/ -c ../etc/httpd1.conf -fvv
```

The `..`'s are to work around busybox's weird interpretation of paths, but the server can be accessed from `127.*`, as expected

However, trying to access it through `::1` gives me a 403 Forbidden response, so I tried to configure it in this manner:

```
$ cat etc/httpd2.conf
A: 127.
A: ::1
D: *
```

This ends up denying all access:

```
$ sudo httpd -h www/ -c ../etc/httpd2.conf -fvv
[::1]:43440: url:/
[::1]:43440: response:403
[::1]:43441: url:/
[::1]:43441: response:403
[::1]:43473: url:/
[::1]:43473: response:403
[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:37889: url:/
[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:37889: response:403
```

I've tried the expanded notation, but that did not work.

How do I configure busybox to allow IPv6 connections?